# Outer measure preserving bijection

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Suppose X is a Sierpinski set (So X is uncountable and every null subset of X is countable). Let f be a bijection on X. Must/Does there exist a non null subset Y of X such that for every subset W of Y, if W has same outer measure as Y, then f[W] has same outer measure as f[Y]?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but, ae you assuming that $X$ is a subset of reals? If not, are you requiring any other kind of properties in its measure?